# android - refer to a color inside a shape

Tags: android, themes

I want to refer to my custom defined color attr inside a shape and it always results in an error.

First i declare the attr:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="divider_color" format="color|reference" />
</resources>
```

In my theme I declare the value:

```
 <style name="myTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
          <item name="divider_color">@color/red</item>
 </style>
```

if I access it like that, it works fine:

```
 android:background="?divider_color"/>
```

but I want to use it inside a shape:

```
<shape
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="?divider_color"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

I receive this error:

**E/AndroidRuntime(3117): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2**

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea.  So I checked out where that exception is originating in the OS: http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/res/TypedArray.java#326

```
307    public int getColor(int index, int defValue) {
308        index *= AssetManager.STYLE_NUM_ENTRIES;
309        final int[] data = mData;
310        final int type = data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_TYPE];
311        if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_NULL) {
312            return defValue;
313        } else if (type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_INT
314            && type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_INT) {
315            return data[index+AssetManager.STYLE_DATA];
316        } else if (type == TypedValue.TYPE_STRING) {
317            final TypedValue value = mValue;
318            if (getValueAt(index, value)) {
319                ColorStateList csl = mResources.loadColorStateList(
320                        value, value.resourceId);
321                return csl.getDefaultColor();
322            }
323            return defValue;
324        }
325
326        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't convert to color: type=0x"
327                + Integer.toHexString(type));
328    }
```

Looks like the 'type' isn't getting interpreted correctly.  This method thinks you're passing in an attribute with type `TYPE_ATTRIBUTE`, as seen [here](http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/frameworks/base/include/utils/ResourceTypes.h#240).  That doesn't answer things, but maybe it can help you narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

You can't until L. 
See here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Android. This has been fixed in Lollipop so should work on L & M but on previous devices it will crash